# Python Twisted Multiple Client Objects

Tags: python, multithreading, networking, twisted

Would this be the appropriate way to create multiple clients on a single machine?

```
def main():
    threads = [None]*10

    for i in range(0, 10):
        threads[i] = ClientFactory()
        reactor.connectTCP('192.168.0.1', 8000, threads[i])

    reactor.run()
```

What I am finding is that when one on the clients receives a response from the server, all of them report that they received a response from the server, according to these epoch time stamps:

```
Connected to server...
Connected to server...
Connected to server...
Connected to server...
1370241372.33
THREAD: 0
1370241372.33
THREAD: 1
1370241372.33
THREAD: 2
1370241372.33
THREAD: 3
1370241376.05
THREAD: 2
1370241376.05
THREAD: 3
1370241376.05
THREAD: 0
1370241376.05
THREAD: 1
```

Are my clients for some reason listening on the same port?  How can I ensure that the appropriate client receives their respective messages?  I have done my best to ensure that the tasks/threads would not simply finish at the same exact time.  Apologies in advance if I have not provided enough to assess the situation.

Also, I realize that an object != thread.  That is just what I called the list.

Comment: First of all, you mislead people, because all this has _absolutely nothing_ to do with threads. Second, please, show your other classes. This part of the code seems fine.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to point out is that you don't need that many `ClientFactory`s. One is enough. But that's not critical.

Comment: Your clients aren't "listening" at all. They're connecting.  Please attach a complete program though; your output shows numerous bits of output, but I don't see any 'print' statements in your code.